For Active Directory Password Retrieval
What are the best practices and methodologies for retrieving a user password from Active Directory?

Pretty simply: you CANNOT under any circumstances do this. No. Way. Period.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In today's world, every sensitive data including passwords are not stored directly, they are stored in hashed format so hacker can't find the sensitive data from storage/database.
All you can do is reset it :

Open Active Directory Users and Computers console (located in the Windows Administrative Tools folder)
In Find Users, Contacts and Groups, search for accounts name
Right-click on User Account and select "Reset Password"
Set new password and click OK


You MUST NOT Capitalize Each And Every Word In An English Text !
